# Is it possible to replace the cover in this old landscape light?

Tags: lighting, landscaping

I don't know what model of light fixture this is. I presume it is a few decades old like the house. It takes GU5.3 bulbs. The cover slips over the body (and the red o-ring) and holds the clear(ish) lens in place. The "lens cover" is very cloudy on both sides from years of exposure. The center is something that is not glass, and the perimeter has a rubberized seal integrated which is in pretty bad shape, making the lights leaky. So cleaning that lens cover, even if possible, wouldn't be enough... ideally I'd like to replace it. Any idea if this is possible?

[image]

Comment: That's probably a bespoke piece designed for the light. At least a model number would be needed. You may also be able to cut a new one from a piece of plexiglass or try the kits that folks use to clear up plastic car headlights.

Comment: @Triplefault thanks for the response. It feels factory made to me, there are a dozen of these around the yard. But aggravating they have no printing on them anywhere identifying company or model. Thanks for the suggestions, will try those if nothing else comes up.

Comment: If wanting to go DIY on it instead of new, large rubber washers from plumbing/conduit and a large o-ring should do.  A couple of washers for the lens cut to size instead of the single gasket should work.

Answer (score 1):

That light looks like a standard Malibu light commonly sold by Home Depot back in the 80's so finding a replacement cover will be almost impossible. The damages done to the lens and socket were caused by the halogen bulbs that were used before the LED bulbs came into existence. Those bulbs were extremely hot. To clean the lense, get some emery paper and light grade oil and rub the lense on both sides. Clean off the rubber seal and add some silicone sealer to the lense and cover. I've also drilled a weep hole at the base for many lights I've serviced in the past. You should be replacing any halogen bulbs with LED bulbs.

In the event you don't want to try to maintain the fixtures, go to your home store and check out what they've got. You can usually get a pack of six for around 80 bucks. They usually come with LED bulbs now.

Answer (score 0):

Finding parts for those lights will take as much time or more that it will to replace a dozen of them.

Replacing parts on 20 yr old landscaping lights make as much sense as putting new tires on a junk car.

Just google "landscaping lights" and find a number of options for replacement.